# jQuery wrap does not work for Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was having this issue where I want to do something like below

```
$("<input type='text'/>").wrap("<div></div>");
```

Was Expecting

```
<div>
 <input type='text'/>
</div>
```

But it did not wrap the input with Div, it gave only 
`<input type='text/>`

Unless I try the other way round.

```
$("<div></div>").append("<input type='text'/>");
```

Anyone can explain? Must I only use the append way to achieve what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

`.wrap` does it exactly what it is supposed to do:

```
console.log($("<input type='text'/>").wrap("<div></div>").parent());
```

It seems you expected that it would return a new set containing the parent (which is reasonable), but that's not the case. It returns the original set of elements.

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong

```
$("`<input type='text'/>`").wrap("<div></div>")
```

you should try

```
$('[type=text]').wrap("<div></div>");
```

you should use selector not element.

Comment: Those two snippets are doing different things.

Comment: Did i said something wrong in my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, bet i will stick to the append way of doing.

Comment: You are completely changing the behavior of the code. What makes you think the OP wants to select an *existing* element in the document? You also claim that `$("<input type='text'/>").wrap("<div></div>")` is wrong without giving an explanation why.

Comment: You are not wrong but what i have is a run time generated Input and to be Wrapped with DIV.. not wrapping any INPUT that it is on the page.

Comment: I just suggested that he should use selector if he wants to use wrap.

Comment: But they want to wrap an element that is not in the document. A selector doesn't find elements not in the document. Besides, the question was *why* `.wrap` behaves like this, for which you have not given an answer.